# How to add an attribute to the element in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, jibx

I'm using jibx to create a xml. the requirement i have is to get Xml as below

```
<report>
  <info>
   <meta name="acntNo">11111111</meta> 
   <meta name="location">USA</meta> 
   <meta name="Id">2222222222</meta> 
  </info>
</report>
```

My Question is how to add **name attribute** to the **complexElement meta**. I'll get the values of name attribute and meta text from java code.

I tried using

```
<xsd:complexType name="CareInfoType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <!--  root of the meta -->
        <xsd:element name="meta" type="qdx:CareMetaInfo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3">
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="CareMetaInfo">
    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" ></xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **xsd:simpleContent** mechanism to add an attribute to an element that can contain values of simple types. You can read the [tutorial here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_simpleContent.asp). Below is another example

**Schema**

```
<xsd:complexType name="SizeType">
  <xsd:simpleContent>
    <xsd:extension base="xsd:integer">
      <xsd:attribute name="system" type="xsd:token"/>
    </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

**Example**

```
<size system="US-DRESS">10</size>
```